# Launch program on client computer when RDP'd into another

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I have two Windows 7 systems: my main laptop I use as my workstation, and a "tech" box that runs Windows 7 Pro, and my management tools. It is headless in the server closet, so I use RDP to access it.

I know with RemoteApp (Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate), you can have just single programs ran through RDP on the client. We only have Windows 7 Pro, but I'd like to duplicate some functionality. When I click a link in the RDP session for a web page from the program, it launches Firefox on the remote screen, as expected. I'd like to have it open with **MY** default browser on my *client* system, similar to how it would with RemoteApp. Is this possible?

Comment: Easy, just upgrade to Enterprise or Ultimate. ;)

Comment: If I was in control of what OS we'd use, then yes; unfortunately, I can only use Professional. Plus, you know, free Linux servers

Comment: When you click a link in the remote session (regardless whether it is Remote Desktop or RemoteApp), it will always open that link inside the remote session (remote IE, remote Firefox). Giving the remote box access to do stuff on the client would be a very high security bug :)